# Making API calls to Skype for Business / Lync without registering application

Tags: skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper, ucwa

I was looking to develop a service that interacts with my Skype for Business account. The [UCWA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/unifiedcommunicationswebapi2_0) API look to be almost perfect (language agnostic HTTP API) unfortunately it seems that using the UCWA API requires registering a persistent(?) application with the Lync server which Id rather not do. I just want to auth, make a few API calls and be done? IS there anyway to do this with Skype for Business / Lync wthout regiersting an application on the server?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused, you don't been to register a application to use UCWA.
You need to register a [azure application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/registeringyourapplicationinazuread) if you want to communicate with SfB online with [UCWA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/authenticationusingazuread) but on-prem [UCWA access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/authenticationinucwa) you don't have to.

I think you are getting confused with [Trusted Application API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/trusted-application-api/docs/overview) which is ONLY for SfB online (it's kind-of like a replacement for UCMA trusted server applications) and only works on SfB online only. You can think of Trusted Application API as a extension of the UCWA api to provide more high-privilege capabilities.  If you don't need the extra capabilities then you don't need to use the Trusted Application API.